# SQL to trigger batch file

Tags: sql-server-2008, batch-file, triggers

We are using SQL Server 2008R2 to handle a mail queue. New mail is entered into the queue and then once every minute a batch file reads the unprocessed mails, does some processing, sends the mail via smtp and flags the mail in the queue as sent (records is not deleted from queue because table also serves as mail history table).

The problem with this method is that it is run only once a minute so mails are not sent out "automatically", and the batch file runs every minute even when there is no outgoing mail for hours.

Is there a way for SQL server to run the batch file on each new item inserted into the mail queue? I know there are triggers but from what i understand they are asynchronous so if the batch file takes time it will hold up sql server

Comment: Why bother with an external batch file? You can easily implement this functionality inside SQL Server directly - would make managing it easier, too. Also: you could create a SQL job that would run every x minutes and check if anything needs to be done - that way, it's decoupled from the "normal" operations of the database and won't interfere with users entering data

Comment: The process that sends the email needs to be run externally as there is some non-related processing done before the send. And the disadvantages with a process that runs every few minutes to check the queue are that it will run many times when not necessary, and on the other hand will seem unresponsive because email will go out after a few minutes instead of immediately.

Comment: Your current solution seems fine. I don't understand your comments about mails not being sent "automatically", because in fact they are. If you need to send a message immediately then email is the wrong mechanism anyway because it isn't designed for that: you have no idea how long it will take to be delivered and/or read. And there's nothing wrong with a service checking the database every few minutes as long as it queries for them efficiently.

Answer (score 1):

I would create a SQL server agent job to run the batch file using a cursor in the job in case there are multiple rows that are updated at once. Create a trigger on the table that runs the agent job. This won't hold up SQL server since it's running through SQL agent. The rows will be processed and the emails sent out immediately.

Answer (score 0):

Are you talking about sending emails from SQL Server?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa155737(v=office.10).aspx

If so, just incorporate the send into your procedure.

If not, assuming you have IIS, don't try to do your own queue.  Create a CLR procedure that adds the email to a .NET queue somewhere such as your batch server.  You can then run a process on your batch server that to read the queue and send the email.  Don't run it periodically - just keep it in a loop that does a blocking read the queue and sends mail.  (You may have to add it to startup/run it periodically or something for resilience and DR reasons).